# .default is not a constructor using declaration file with javascript package

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using external javascript package, which doesn't have default export and declaration file. I thought of writing one myself, but I have a problem importing it after I do just that. 
Javascript package that I wrote declaration file to looks like this:

```
function Speech() {
    // code
}

Speech.prototype.say = function (saying) {
    // code
};

module.exports = Speech;
```

My declaration file:

```
declare class Speech() {
   constructor()
   say(saying: string): Speech
}
export default Speech
```

When I try to import this package in my .ts files using imports like this:

```
import Speech from './index'
```

And try to initialize it:

```
const speech = new Speech()
```

I get an error saying `index_1.default is not a constructor`.

If I import module using another import like:

```
import Speech = require('./index')
```

It works as intended and doesn't throw any errors.

Is it possible to somehow fix declaration file, so that I could use default imports and I wouldn't have to use require?

Or is using import with require the right way in my situation?

Thanks

Comment: You're mixing commonJS with ES Modules and typescript. Have you tried importing the commonJS module directly using `import Speech from './path/to/speech.js';` ? But I have no idea how Typescript will mangle this up during the transpilation phase.

Comment: Yeah, importing from js files like you said works perfectly. I used to do it, when I was coding using JS. The reason I added declaration file is to have autocomplete and stop TS from asking me for default exports.

Comment: The duplicate questions all seem to refer to the `import Speech = require('./index')` syntax to mix all 3 of these together correctly, so I have a hunch you're stuck with this.

Comment: Enable `esModuleInterop` in your TS config.

Comment: I know about the flag that ignores no default export error. I was just thinking maybe there is another way to write declaration file, so that I could import module as a default import. Are there any drawbacks of using import x = require(y) compared to default import?